Long multiply and int multiply are not same value
i have two equation
int.Parse("75192")  * 598500
          

the result

2052739040

long.Parse("75192")  * 598500

the result

49502653200

when i use calculator or php code i always get the second result "49502653200"
how i can get the result "2036954352" using calculator or php code
or convert "45002412000" to "2036954352"
-- EDIT --
Problem solved based on "Yonghwan Kim" answer
 long longValue = long.Parse("75192") * 30 * 10 * 1995;  // <-- it will be "45002412000"
 byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(longValue);
 int intValue2 = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0); // <-- it will be "2052739040"


Int has only 32bit, so the multiplication overflows.

I got 2052739040 https://dotnetfiddle.net/OKlYCz

@shingo thanks but I need it in php

So you want it to overflow?? ie you want the first incorrect result not the correct one

I just want to tell you that my result is different than yours.

If you calculate this value as a 32-bit int variable, an overflow occurs and the value received is incorrect.
To get accurate results, you must receive it as a 64-bit long variable.
Nevertheless, if you try to receive it in int type, you must take into account that the value after the 32nd bit is ignored.
Refer to the code below and check that the bit array is truncated when receiving a long variable as an int variable.
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int intValue = int.Parse("75192") * 598500;
        long longValue = long.Parse("75192") * 598500;

        // check real result
        Console.WriteLine(intValue);  // <-- it will be "2052739040"
        Console.WriteLine(longValue);   // <-- it will be "45002412000"

        // get bitarray for longValue
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(longValue);
        System.Collections.BitArray b = new System.Collections.BitArray(bytes);

        // display bit array for longValue
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(b[i] ? "1" : "0");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        //get bitarray for intValue
        System.Collections.BitArray c = new System.Collections.BitArray(new int[] { intValue });

        // display bit array for intValue
        sb.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(c[i] ? "1" : "0");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        // take first 32 bits from bitarray of longValue and convert to int
        int intValue2 = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

        Console.WriteLine(intValue2.ToString());

    }
} 

